# While loop stuck in infinite loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I cannot figure out why this function gets stuck. 
What I am trying to do is create a folder from a predetermined start date up until the present month. Unfortunately it completes all the folder creations then gets stuck with the arithmetic posted below. 
Would anyone be able to give me a hint to get on to the right track?
Here is my code:

```
yearloop(){
   year=$(echo "$firstmsgdate"|cut -d"/" -f3)
   zmmailbox -z -m $account gf /archive || zmmailbox -z -m $account cf /archive
   crntmnth=$(date +"%m")
   incmonth=0
   while [ $year -le $currentyear ]; do
     if [ "$year" -lt "$currentyear" ]; then
       #do stuff
       let year++
     elif [ $year -eq $currentyear ]; then
       while [ $incmonth -lt $crntmnth ]; do
         #do otherthings
         let incmonth++
       done
     else
       echo "Else"
     fi
   done
}
```

This is the output I receive
    + '[' 15 -le 15 ']'
    + '[' 15 -lt 15 ']'
    + '[' 15 -eq 15 ']'
    + '[' 2 -lt 02 ']'
    + '[' 15 -le 15 ']'
    + '[' 15 -lt 15 ']'
    + '[' 15 -eq 15 ']'
    + '[' 2 -lt 02 ']'
    + '[' 15 -le 15 ']'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the year reaches current year, it's never incremented again (the `elif` is in effect), so the outer `while` loop which tests "less than or equal to" is still in effect. Put `let year++` after the `while` loop in the `elif` part, and it will work. Or even better... call `break` explicitly at that point. It's never good to rely on the `while` loop to terminate on its own.

Additionally, you could simply use sequences and skip all the clumsy tests:

```
#initialization as before
let lastyear=currentyear-1
for year in $(seq $year $lastyear); do
   #do stuff with $year
done
#now months of the current year
for month in $(seq $incmonth $crntmnth); do
   #do stuff with $month and $currentyear
done
```

Your double loop was useless anyway - current year only happens once.